# can not use BCrypt in java Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, bcrypt, password-encryption, jbcrypt

I want to use bcrypt encryption for user password.
I download bcrypt zip file bcrypt 1.1.zip and add it to my project build path in eclipse.
Now when I want to use BCrypt in servlet it gives an error BCrypt can not be resolved.
I dont know how to overcome this.Please explain me.

Comment: did you extract the jbcrypt.jar from it and add it to your class path?

Comment: it contains .exe and .dll file not .jar file

Comment: Then you need to download the api jar file. Not the executable. You can only run the executable as a child process.

Comment: ok i download the jar

Comment: No question is stupid. Everyone learns only by asking questions, silly or not. Keep learning.

Comment: i Downloaded jbcrypt-0.2.jar from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjbcrypt02jar.htm .there is no problem while writing code.But when i run program it throws an exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mindrot/jbcrypt/BCrypt

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjbcrypt02jar.htm says that it contains org.mindrot.BCrypt.java but ir really does not contains